# Ask agents to check their position

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am trying to create links for each agent with 7 other agents 
my study area is divided in two sides "east and west" 
I am using GIS extension and the side of the city is an attribute within the Shapefile, 
I want to ask my agent to check the side of the city where it is in and create links with 7 other agents from the same side I am using two if statements

here's my code :

```
to Neighbour-network   
ask households [ 
    if patch-here [CitySide = "EAST"] [ create-links-with min-n-of 7 other households with [CitySide = "EAST"] [distance myself][
      if patch-here [CitySide = "WEST"] [ create-links-with min-n-of 7 other households with [CitySide = "WEST"] [distance myself]]]]]   
ask one-of households with [count link-neighbors > 1]   [
        ask link-neighbors [communicate]] 
    end
```

the error that i get is related to patch-here the message error is :  if expected this input to be a True/False but got a patch instead 
however when change it to patches with the error become :  if expected this input to be a True/False but got an agentset instead

I am not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

`CitySide` seems to be a `households-own` variable.  Is it also a `patches-own` variable?  If so, then your `if` statements should be

```
if [CitySide] of patch-here = 'EAST` [ create-links .....
```

and

```
if [CitySide] of patch-here = 'WEST` [ create-links .....
```

But, if the household has its own `CitySide` variable that tells it where it is, why does it need to look at the patch it is on?  Can't it just look at its own `CitySide` variable?

Comment: Since turtles can directly access patch variables at their location, if it's a `patches-own` then it's even simpler `if CitySide = "EAST" [ ...`